# NumberFormatException for Long

Tags: java

I have defined one variable as Long. And if someone passes String to that variable it throws NumberFormatException. How can i throw my own message. Like only Long values are allowed. I'm doing:

Long period;
But instead of Long value someone entered String. Then it should through error

Comment: Catch the `NumberFormatException`, then `throw`  your own exception .

Comment: You can use try catch block with message in catch block only when NumberFormatException occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like below.

```
try {
        ....////
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("The value you entered, " + value+ " is invalid.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch and re-throw your own exception

```
try {
  l = Long.parseLong(text);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only long values are allowed", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own `Exception`:

```
class LongValueException extends Exception {

    public LongValueException () {
    }

    public LongValueException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then call it in your `try...catch`:

```
try{
    Long.parseLong(yourString);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e){
    throw new LongValueException ("Only long can be used here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write regexp for long. After that you should check your long string for regexp. If string does not match pattern then you can log error message.

```
String longRegexp = "^-?[0-9]{1,19}$";
if(!yourLong.matches(longRegexp )){
    //Log it.
}
```